# Node-postgres Inserting a new record into my database does not return the new entry's data

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, node-postgres

Here's the route from which the query is being executed:

```
userRouter.route("/new")
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var user = req.body;
        pg.connect(connectionString, function (error, client, done) {
            var queryString = "INSERT INTO Users (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (" + "'" + [user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name].join("','") + "'" + ")";
            console.log(queryString);
            client.query(queryString, function (error, result) {
                console.log(result.rows);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
```

The problem is that the "result" value I'm attempting to reference from within the second console is basically blank:

```
{
  command: 'INSERT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: 0,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false,
  _getTypeParser: [Function: bound ]
 }
```

Shouldn't result.rows contain an array containing an object representing the row I just created in the database?

Comment: So if you do `console.log(result.rows[0])` you get nothing, is that right?

Comment: I get an empty array. []

Comment: Is the row actually getting inserted correctly?

Comment: Yes. The database is updated with the new row.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on then, it looks fine, `result.rows[0]` should contain the row. You should probably look at correctly using stored procedures rather than concatenating quotes and input values though. e.g `client.query("INSERT INTO items(text, complete) values($1, $2)", [data.text, data.complete])`

Answer (score 18):

All right, I've figured it out.

Apparently, I was attempting to use a feature that has not yet been implemented in Node-Postgres, as described here: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Todo

**Insert/update/select row count in query result callback**

> Though this would be extremely awesome off course, it is possible to
>   obtain the behaviour by adding RETURNING id or even RETURNING * to the
>   query. This works fine for single columns for me. I will test this for
>   multiples and the handling of that case by this package. I am quite
>   certain it must be possible in postgres.

So, I updated my query to return all data for the new row:

```
var queryString = "INSERT INTO Users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (" + "'" + [user.first_name, user.last_name].join("','") + "'" + ") RETURNING *";
```

And then I modified my query to account for the "row" event handler, which is trigger when a new row is entered into the database. It is within the context of this event handler that the new row data is accessible to me (as per the "RETURNING" parameter above:

```
var query = client.query(queryString, function (error, result) {
    done();
});

query.on("row", function (row, result) {
    console.log("Inside the row event handler.");
    res.render("users/show", { user: row });
});
```

Aaaand it works!

Comment: I think your query is vulnerable to sql injection. Use pg feature of templating with `client.query('INSERT INTO Users (first_name, last_name) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [user.first_name, user.last_name])`. It has build-in sanitazing.

Answer (score 12):

update the query and add at the end of the query   " **RETURNING *** "

```
  var queryString = "INSERT INTO Users (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (" + "'" + [user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name].join("','") + "'" + ") RETURNING *";
```

get    **result.rows[0]**

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RETURNING fieldName1, fieldName or *` in the query is the solution for the above problem.

Working Perfectly!